# Point displays in map even though Symbology visibility set to false in arcgis pro

Tags: arcgis

Using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3.  I have a point feature class that I setup with labels and am hiding the symbology point by unchecking the visibility box:

[image]

However when I share the map feature layer to arcgis online, it still shows the point in arcgis online for each feature even though it's visibility was unchecked in arcgis pro.  This is the point in arcgis online:

[image]

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this. While I wasn't able to make the point disappear as I hoped setting the transparency to 100% for both the fill and outline of the point will provided the output I was looking for. This can be done with the color properties in ArcGIS Pro symbology.

Comment: Hi Kori, I did do the transparency workaround for the symbology color originally and it works.  However, I do not feel this would be an acceptable work-around.  The issue here is a clear bug between arcgis pro and arcgis online.  Thank you for your contribution and suggestion.